# Exported svg dosen't show text

Tags: html, css, svg

So I wrote some text in Figma and added a stroke to it. After I exported it as an SVG file, only the stroke remained and the text(which is white) doesn't appear with it. How do I fix this so the svg I export will have the stroke and the text?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDd15.jpg

heres the link to the png version which works but has a lower resolution

I hope to be able to get the text in my svg file along with the stroke as well

Comment: Please provide a minimal, complete and verifiable test case of the exported code.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue - in my case the font wasn't installed on the machine I was running on (using Inkscape). The exportef `svg` referred to the right font, but no conversion could be done.

If that's not the case, open the svg in your favorite editor and see what is being output - that should help with debugging the problem